# Count node depth in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have this query in Neo4j:

```
MATCH (sentence:Sentence)-[r*]->(n:Word )
WITH n, COUNT(r) AS c
RETURN n, c
```

My graph is a linguistic database containing words and dependency relations between them.
This query should return depth of nodes, however the COUNT(r) always returns 1.
When I ommit the COUNT function and write just

```
WITH n, r AS c
```

instead (trying in web browser neo4j interface), neo4j returns multiple relations for each word node "n" as expected.
Can you please help me what am I doing wrong, how to count the length of path between sentence node and word node? thanks.

Comment: Can you describe your Neo4j data? so that we can figure it out whats wrong there.

Comment: See my own answer below. The data is just a forest of sentence trees as I said, I needed to calculate distance of a node (word in sentence) from root. The solution is LENGTH(r), not COUNT(r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it query return n and c and there are multiple record of n so count(r) return 1.

Try this -

```
MATCH (sentence:Sentence)-[r*]->(n:Word )
WITH n, LENGTH(r) AS depth
RETURN n, depth
```

You will get depth like this.

Or Try this

```
   MATCH p= (sentence:Sentence)-->(n:Word)    
   RETURN n, length(p) as depth
```

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-length

Comment: No difference - all "total_count" values are again "1".

Comment: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-size

Answer (score 1):

In version 4.x, U should use **SIZE** function

```
MATCH (sentence:Sentence)-[r*]->(n:Word )
WITH n, SIZE(r) AS depth
RETURN n, depth
```

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-size

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution myself - it is cypher's LENGTH function:

```
MATCH (sentence:Sentence)-[r*]->(n:Word )
WITH n, LENGTH(r) AS c
RETURN n, c
```

found in this useful cheat sheet: http://assets.neo4j.org/download/Neo4j_CheatSheet_v3.pdf