# Neo4j max depth and path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The simple question is: How to calculate the maximum depth value and the maximum depth path from a node using neo4j (2.3.11) cypher?

### Explanation of my scenario

I have node label called **person** and relationship types called **supervised**.

Think in a scenario: a node **1** can supervise **2**, **2** can supervise **3** and **4**, **4** can supervise **5** and so on.

So 1 need of:

1. I want to make a cypher, that receive the id, e.g. 1(personID), as parameter, and return the path [1, 2, 4, 5 ....]
2. And another cypher that returns the path count.

---

I tried that cypher (neo4j 2.3.11) for the second case, without success:

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[SUPERVISED*]->()
WITH person, LENGTH(SUPERVISED) AS depth
where person.personID = 'la3486551918237738'
RETURN person, depth;
```

Based in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089984/count-node-depth-in-neo4j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the max depth and the list of IDs in a single query:

```
MATCH path=(person:Person)-[:supervised*]->(x)
WHERE person.personID = 'la3486551918237738' AND NOT EXISTS((x)-[:supervised]->())
WITH person, path
ORDER BY LENGTH(path) DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN person, [n IN NODES(path) | n.personID] AS ids, LENGTH(path) AS depth
```

Notes:

- I assume that `supervised` is the required relationship type. Note that a colon must precede the relationship type when used in a Cypher pattern, as in `[:supervised*]`.
- The `NOT EXISTS((x)-[:supervised]->())` test requires that the paths found end with a leaf node.
- `ORDER BY LENGTH(path) DESC LIMIT 1` picks the longest path.

[UPDATE]

I found the following problems in [your sample data linked to in the comments](https://gist.github.com/jmmccota/3cc576b979b141af09d7498e621618a0):

1. None of the `Relations.csv` file's `studentID`s appear as a `personID` in `Nodes.csv`. (Since you indicated that this is just an oversight in the sample, I just fixed this in my own copy of the files.)
2. The first `LOAD CSV` query contains an unneeded `OPTIONAL MATCH`.
3. The second `LOAD CSV` query is requires the `csvFile.institution` property, but the `Relations.csv` file does not contain an `institution` header (it has a `university_name` header instead). So, replacing `csvFile.institution` with `csvFile.university_name` fixes the second query.

Comment: I tried that, but with no result :(

     {
        "columns": ["person", "ids", "depth"],
        "data": [],
        "stats": {
        "contains_updates": false,
        "nodes_created": 0,
        "nodes_deleted": 0,
        "properties_set": 0,
        "relationships_created": 0,
        "relationship_deleted": 0,
        "labels_added": 0,
        "labels_removed": 0,
        "indexes_added": 0,
        "indexes_removed": 0,
        "constraints_added": 0,
        "constraints_removed": 0
      }
    }

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that shows the issue?

Comment: Can I send csv with data? or do you preffer print screen or another type?

Comment: I possible, use a Cypher statement to create the data.

Comment: I have created a gist https://gist.github.com/jmmccota/3cc576b979b141af09d7498e621618a0

Comment: None of the `studentID`s in your relationship file match a `personID` from your nodes file. Therefore, the `MATCH (student:Person {personID: csvFile.studentID})` clause will never succeed and that query will never proceed further.

Comment: He performs the correspondence, otherwise in the real case it wouldn't work.. My date-set has about 500mb, do you want it to perform a test?

Comment: I'm not understanding your comment. Does your data actually contain a `personID` that matches a `studentID`?

Comment: Yes. StudentId is a column from my csv(raw data). In the full data, the relationships exist.

Comment: See my upodate.

Comment: Thank you ... After reading, I think this data-set was modeled relational, not being the best way for a graph database like neo4j